# Repeating section in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jquery, content-editor-web-part

Just wondering has anyone ever found a solution for creating a repeating section on a SharePoint 2013 built in SharePoint designer and NOT Infopath.

All resources online point to using the repeating section tool in Infopath but none actually give help on how to create a repeating group of fields / section in SharePoint designer or using JQuery or Content Editor for example.

I alreay have built a form and simply want to repeat certain fields so that I can insert more than piece of data for certain columns but still keep it so that it is one item being added to the SharePoint list.

Thanks in Advance,

Ryan

EDITED***
[image: Screenshot 1 of Form]

[image: Screenshot 2 of Form]

Comment: Do you want to add different data for the same column multiple times i mean to ask repetitively?If so then you can use JSOM but again it depends on which type of column you want to do so.Can you share your form and field details here to better understand your requirement?

Comment: Hi @InnovaITveSolutions. I have attached my created form above. Basically what I am after is for a user to be able to enter the first 5 fields once only and then be able to enter all other fields multiple times. So what I would require would be some sort of button which could be clicked and would produce a duplicate form (minus the first five fields as these will be consistent throughout the submission). Im not sure if this is possible on SharePoint as I have no experience of doing something like this before. Even an accordion type layout or repeating section. Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add a repeating section in your sharepoint list form without using infopath, even with infopath you have very limited options if your form is browser based. I had to use an alternate way to change the way you get input from user. I loaded the task titles from an another list and and displayed these titles in a multi selection list box. So user only selects the tasks and submits the form. Through my workflow I then created the tasks and later user had to assign each task which was created by the workflow.